# Matlab -Comparing Values in a Matrix Without using loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab

As you know, using loops with big size matrix results delay, in my   case I need to  free my code of loops for the same reason(delay). This is my code example:

```
for i=1:n
    for j=1:m-1
       Z=A(i,j);
       Z2= A(i,j+1);

       if X(Z,Z) == X(Z2,Z)
          X(Z2,Z) = X(Z2,Z)+1;
       end

     end
 end
```

So, are there any suggestion? Many thanks.

Comment: Is this a working code? Do you get the output you want from it? Is `A` an array of integers representing indices in `X`? And what is `X`? Can you post some small sample of `A` and `X`?

Comment: since you are updating `X` as well as testing its values at each iteration the output is likely to depend on the order of the loop (and `A`) therefore any vectorization may SIGNIFICANTLY change the output.

Comment: @Mark BTW, it is best [not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: Hello Robert ,thank you for responding , yes , I got results from this code, this code compares two values if they are identical , the code add one to one  of the values  to make it  different from the other one , these are the inputs and the results:
  A=[1  4]
    [ 1  5]
    [ 1  6]
    [ 2  8];


    X=[1     0  ]   
      [ 0     1 ]    
      [ 0     0 ]    
      [ 1     0  ]   
      [ 1     0  ]   
      [ 1     0  ]  
      [ 0     0  ]   
      [ 0     1  ];

    Results:
      [ 1 0]
[0 1]
[0 0]
[2 0]
[2 0]
[2 0]
[0 0]
[0 2];

Comment: Thank you Shai,I agree with you. Thanks for help.